# BehaviorSubject to track input value live across components

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a BehaviorSubject that works on button click, but I'm trying to figure out how to type in an input field in the header component and output it in realtime in the output component on the page without having to click a button to transmit. It should just transmit as I type.
Any help is appreciated!

search.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SearchService{
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("default message");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  constructor(){ }
  changeMessage(message: string){
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }
}
```

header.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { SearchService } from './search.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  message: string;
  searchField: string;
  constructor( private searchService: SearchService ) { }




  ngOnInit(){

    this.searchService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
  }




newMessage() {
  this.searchService.changeMessage(this.searchField);
}

  }
```

Output Component

```
import { SearchService } from '../header/search.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-output',
  templateUrl: './output.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./output.component.css']
})
export class OutputComponent implements OnInit {

  message: string;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {


      this.searchService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);

  }
```

Comment: If I understood this correctly, you just want to bind the input field on header with your search service and then same has to reflect on output component if that page is already loaded into DOM?
correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. The header search field is eventually going to filter out json data results in the output component as I type

Comment: How do you call 'newMessage' inside your template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the `input` event on your Header component template to your Header compenent class.

On your header.component.html,

```
<input (input)="onInput($event)"/>
```

And on your header.component.ts,

```
onInput(event) {
  const { value } = event.target;
  // console.log(value);
  this.searchService.changeMessage(value);
}
```

This will ensure the the `messageSource` (which is a `BehaviorSubject`) property in your service will contain the input text values everytime the user keys in anything on the input on your Header component.

Answer (score 0):

So its pretty simple to bind.
In your header component on each keystroke just emit the BehaviourSubject and wherever observable of that subject is subscribed will get to know the changes.

**in header html**

```
<input (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"/>
```

**in header ts file**

```
onChange(value) {
this.searchService.changeMessage(value);
```

}